# Python scikit learn import error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to learn text classification using [SVM classifier](http://www.tp.umu.se/~nylen/pylect/advanced/scikit-learn/index.html#support-vector-machines-svms-for-classification), for this I am experimenting example code from [sci-kit learn](http://www.tp.umu.se/~nylen/pylect/advanced/scikit-learn/index.html#support-vector-machines-svms-for-classification), but when I import following command

```
from scikits.learn import svm
```

I get the error as shown in the following figure.

[image]

FYI, I installed scikit-learn in **Mac OS-X 10.8.5**.I also can run following command without any error

```
import sklearn.svm
import sklearn.cluster
import sklearn
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just import `from sklearn import svm`. The documentation you are refering to is about an old version of the library with a different namespace. The up to date version of this tutorial is maintained at: http://scipy-lectures.github.io/packages/scikit-learn/index.html